# D3.js How to dynamically assign years in javascript functions using drop down box

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had developed D3.js line chart using javascript functions,i had selected dropdown box in years but first one will be shown but remaining was unable shown,i had wrote given data.

```
            var data=[{"key":[2000,0],"value":100},{"key":[2000,1],"value":200},{"key":[2001,0],"value":300},{"key":[2001,1],"value":400}];
        <select id="year" onchange="line2ChartFun()"> 
        <option value="2009"selected="selected">Choose a year</option>
        <option value="2009">2000</option>
        <option value="2010">2001</option>
        </select>
        var years=2000;

        function funMonths(){
          var arr=[];
          for(i in data){
          var obj={};
          obj.key=new Date(data[i].key[0],data[i].key[1])
          obj.value=data[i].value;
          if(data[i].key[0]==years){
          arr.push(obj)
          }
          }
          return arr;
          }
          var funName=funMonths();
          console.log(funName);
          How to dynamically assign years in javascript functions when click in the drop down box.
 function line2ChartFun(){
          d3.select("#year")
         .call(funMonths())
         }
```

Comment: sorry but it is not very clear. Could you please improve the description of what you want and what error you have got ?

Comment: when i have to select 2010 then display the detailes of the 2010 but enable to show to click drop down list